# how to insert section, paragraph or specific lines from external pdf into LaTeX document

Tags: sectioning, pdf, pdfpages

I was just wondering if there was any way to insert section, paragraph or lines from external pdf into a LaTeX document. I have a little knowledge about how to insert pdf pages by page number or range of pages using `pdfpages` package. Any help will be highly appreciated.

For example, the following is the section of a pdf document

[image]

Comment: As far as I know there is a clip function for pdfpages.

Comment: Welcome to txe.se. `\includegraphics*` command from `graphicx` package can also clip. In a PDF, anything can appear anywhere on the page, so the concept of "line" or "paragraph" does not really apply.